# Build a dependent Jenkins job and copy artifact before building a jenkins job

Tags: selenium, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I have below scenario with Jenkins.

I have a Job X which I want to trigger. Whenever I trigger the job X, it has to trigger the another job A and copy the build artifact to project X and then X should be built. Is there any way this can be achieved?

Why I need the artifact? The project A contains all the common utils which is used (as a dependent in pom) in Projects X, Y and Z. For this reason, I need to build the project A first and copy the jar to the project X or Y or Z whatever is triggered

Comment: you can achieve through post-build action

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have used Jenkins Pre Steps (Trigger or call Builds on Other Project) by setting up the other Project